# Do I need to learn Javascript before AJAX or does AJAX not require Javascript knowledge?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was wondering if it is worth learning javascript first? Does AJAX require Javascript in anyway or is it just similarities in the markup language?

Comment: Javascript is not a markup language. And AJAX is not a language at all.

Comment: Do you know what *J* stands for in *AJAX*?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz - ironic when the thing the _X_ stands for is optional (and in my experience less common than other formats). For that matter the _A_ is optional too (though highly desirable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, learn the basics of JavaScript. It's a programming language, not a markup language. You don't need to become an expert immediately, but learn the basics — what it is, the basic structures (functions, control flow statements, variables, objects, etc.), that sort of thing.

Ajax is a technique for retrieving data in a web page without refreshing the full content of the page (or indeed, any of it if you don't want to). You perform Ajax operations (sending a request, interpreting the response) using JavaScript and some other things, such as the `XMLHttpRequest` object. Ajax isn't a part of JavaScript. They're just used together in the web environment.

---

(Side note: Although Ajax stands for "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML", the XML part of that is optional; you can do "Ajax" without using XML and in fact, many if not most people do. Ajax lets you send and retrieve all kinds of data, including XML but also including HTML, JSON, plain text, and lots of other stuff.)

---

Some references that may be useful:

- JavaScript:

  - The [Mozilla JavaScript pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)
  - *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by David Flanagan (yes, an old-fashioned paper book)
  - [Crockford's articles on JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com) (a bit advanced, wait 'till you're ready). Crockford is smart and knowledgeable, but not everyone agrees with all of his conclusions. (I don't.) But it's good to read and understand his points, and make your own decisions. He's mostly right, most of the time.
  - [My own anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org) (start with the oldest entries and work forward)
  - The ECMAScript specification ([PDF](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) | [handy HTML version](http://es5.github.com/))
- The DOM

  - [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
  - [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
  - [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
  - [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/#auto-toc-6)
- (Speaking of which) The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). Parts of it are just codifying what web browsers actually do right now; other parts of it specify new stuff. Mostly you can tell which is which by checking whether the thing in question is part of [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/). If it is, then likely the HTML5 spec tells you what browsers mostly do today. If it isn't, then it's new and browser support may be perfect, or may be non-existant. :-)
- The API docs for the library you choose. There are several good ones: [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). (jQuery is the most widely-used at present.)

Comment: Does Ajax require the use of JQuery. Would I essentially need to learn js - jquery - ajax in that order?

Comment: @Chrism: Nothing requires use of jQuery, jQuery is just a library designed to make some things easier when doing client-side web programming. There are several others. jQuery is a good one, it's actively maintained, and widely-used. (I use it, and recommend it, but that's me.) For a quick study guide, I'd say: JavaScript, the API of the library you're going to use, browse the DOM specifications so you understand what the library is using under-the-covers. (The API of the library will show you how to do Ajax with it; if you're not going to use a lib, look up the `XMLHttpRequest` object.)

Answer (score 7):

You should absolutely learn javascript. And because AJAX is achieved with javascript, by learning javascript you will also learn AJAX. [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is not a different language. It's a pattern that you could use to develop asynchronous web applications using javascript.

Also note that javascript is not a markup language.

Comment: *"And because AJAX achieved with javascript, by learning javascript you will also learn AJAX."* Er, no. You *use* JavaScript if you want to do Ajax, but learning JavaScript won't ipso facto teach you anything about Ajax. Learning JavaScript *from examples based on web browsers and using Ajax techniques* would, though.

Comment: So does ajax use the same methods, functions etc as js? Would i write an ajax code using javascript essentially?

Comment: @Chrism, essentially you will implement AJAX using javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but here's an analogy if it helps...

- Learning JavaScript is like learning to ride a motorcycle.
- Learning AJAX is like learning a technique or trick you can do on that motorcycle, like pop a wheelie *(though AJAX is more practical than that)*.
- Learning jQuery is like getting some gear to *(perhaps)* make your motorcycle ride safer or more enjoyable, like a helmet and leather chaps and jacket, or a more comfortable seat and better shocks, or maybe some saddlebags.

So the base of everything is JavaScript. AJAX is just a term to describe something you do in JavaScript, and jQuery is a code library that you may enjoy using when developing in JavaScript, but isn't at all required.

Comment: Wait, you're saying wheelies aren't practical?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Nah, I'm just bitter because I don't have a motorcycle anymore, and never learned to do a wheelie. ;)

Comment: Ah. I have a motorcycle but I can't do wheelies - would be cool to learn, but I don't want to risk damage to _my_ bike. (I can do 'em on a bicycle, does that count?) +1.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yeah, that counts 'cause I probably can't even do that without hurting myself!

Comment: Wheelies are totally practical, like if your front wheel comes off while doing a wheelie you can still ride.

Comment: @DaveNewton: So *that* must be the reason why they invented wheelies!

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, AJAX is a technology that uses javascript for 'part of the work' (it stands for Asyncronous JavaScript and XML), and handling it properly requires knowing at least something about javascript.  Also, using a javascript library such as jQuery or Prototype make it much easier to work with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a language, AJAX is a technology performed using JavaScript (and usually a web server).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is 98% Javascript and 2% other. Even the JSON(Javascript Object Notation) you would use for the response data type format, if you choose to, is Javascript. I think this answers your question.