# Is order relevant when learning JavaScript, Ajax, jQuery and JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

The number of jobs I could apply for would greatly increase if I knew JavaScript, AJAX, jQuery and JSON. I've begun teaching myself and figured out, in some sense or another, they have all evolved from JavaScript. My question is how well (if at all) do you need to know one before learning the other and in what order?

Comment: JavaScript > jQuery + AJAX > JSON would be a logical order (note: JSON is the **JavaScript** Object notation. "JSON" comes last, because it's often used in web services).

Comment: The question will be closed I guess, because it will lead to expressing opinions. You should certainly learn Javascript first.

Comment: I agree with Rob W. You must learn the base language before you start learning libraries. jQuery makes AJAX so much easier, so learn it before AJAX. Same with jQuery/JSON

Comment: This question is inappropriate here. It calls for opinion and discussion. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is quite clear about these types of questions being a poor fit for the SO format. Voting to close as "not constructive".

Comment: I've worked my way through this JavaScript tutorial, am I ready for jQuery? http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/ in other words is there anything specific I should no about JavaScript?

Comment: **@Celeritas**: [JQ Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/), [Essential JS Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/), [JavaScript The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742). Start there.

Comment: See [do-i-need-to-learn-javascript-before-ajax-or-does-ajax-not-require-javascript-kn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811605/do-i-need-to-learn-javascript-before-ajax-or-does-ajax-not-require-javascript-kn)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. **Javascript**. As this is the language that surrounds the other things you want to learn, it's logical to start here. Find out what Javascript is, the syntax, what it can do (and CAN'T do).
2. **jQuery** (mind the single r) is a Javascript-library, it means that it is just another way to write plain js-functions. You can do everything jQuery can in pure Javascript. The difference is that jQuery makes many things easier and corrects some flaws browsers have developed (hello IE).
3. **Ajax** (transferring information without pageload) is a feature in Javascript. You could either learn the pure js-way, or the simplified jQuery-way. I love how simple jQuery have made ajax-calls. My ajax-calls before I began learning jQuery was a mess! This is just an aspect of the entire jQuery-library, so some basic knowledge of their syntax, event-handling and such is smart before beginning to learn this.
4. **JSON** is just a way to encode a set of strings when you are using Ajax. With some basic knowledge of Javascript, this should not take you a long time to figure out.

That is the order I would suggest. With my comments you can see `why` I suggest them in this order.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

1. **Javascript** is the core of all the ones you listed as everything you've listed is written in javascript or uses its syntax.  You will need to know core javascript in order to learn/use any of the other items you've listed.
2. **jQuery** is a popular and useful library built on top of javascript that adds lot of useful functionality and implements a lot of cross browser compatibility for you.
3. **Ajax.**  You will probably want to learn the ajax stuff in jQuery as it makes ajax a lot easier than doing plain javascript ajax.
4. **JSON** is the data format often used with Ajax so you will probably encounter it while learning ajax.

I would suggest the order above.

Comment: I noticed the change and changed my comment

Comment: Still surprised at the downvotes since my answer was actually posted before the accepted answer and lists the same items in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is the language itself so you should learn it first. JSON is the javascript object notation so while you're learning Javascript you will be learning it too. Ajax is the API for async calls to the server so it has its own object which is consumed using JS. jQuery is a library which is built on top of JS.