# Submit and Generate Dynamic PHP Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with text boxes and drop down menus. One of the drop down menus is Dependant on the value of another, e.g. `InventoryUsage` is dependent on the value in `InventoryID`.

So far I have done the entire site using PHP since I do not know JavaScript, though I found a JavaScript function that can get the value entered in `InventoryID`, but I cannot use that value in the PHP since PHP is server-side.

What I need to do is change the second dropdown options depending on that of the first dropdown. Then submit the data as I would with a normal form.

Edit:

I used ob_start and included the tpl page and sent all the variables to the page which were pulled from the database prior. All the variables have the same index meaning that InventoryID['0']=ID3456 corresponds to InventoryUsage['0']=60. Therefore when InventoryID is ID3456 i would like to display the Number located at InventoryUsage['0']. I hope this adds some context to the problem.

The index is determined by the php variable $i in my code snippet. The $i would be changed to match the index of the InventoryID field. Say the value of InventoryUsage is 20 then I want to display numbers 1 to 20.

Snippet of code below:

```php
<label>TypeOfSurgery</label> <input type="text" name="TypeOfSurgery"          size="35" value="" />
<label>CauseOfSurgery</label> <input type="text" name="CauseOfSurgery" size="35" value="" />
<label>AnaesthesiaUsage</label> <input type="text" name="AnaesthesiaUsage" size="35" value="" />
<label>SurgeryOutcome </label> <input type="text" name="SurgeryOutcome" size="35" value="" />
<label>RecoveryTime</label> <input type="text" name="RecoveryTime" size="35" value="" />
<label>Stages </label> <input type="text" name="Stages" size="35" value="" />
<label>EmployeeName  </label> <p>
<select name="EmployeeName">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
for($i=0;!empty($EmployeeName[$i]);$i++)
echo '<option value="">'.$EmployeeName[$i].'</option>';
?>
</select><p>
<label>Cost</label> <input type="text" name="Cost" size="35" value="" />
<label>InventoryID</label> <p>
<select name="InventoryID">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
for($i=0;!empty($InventoryID[$i]);$i++)
echo '<option value="">'.$InventoryID[$i].'</option>';
?>
</select><p>
<label>InventoryUsage </label> <p>
<select name="InventoryUsage">
<option value=""></option>

<script type="text/javascript">
var model= document.getElementById('InventoryUsage');
</script>
<?php
//if inventory in 
for($i=0;!empty($InventoryUsage[$i]);$i++)
echo '<option value="">'.$InventoryUsage[$i].'</option>';
?>
</select><p>
```

Comment: This is really not a job for PHP. You need javascript for this.

Comment: But the variables I am using are returned to the form page using php. If I understand correctly I cannot use javascript to get that data from those variables. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What you need is to use a ajax function to submit the values and with the result redraw the second dropdown.

Comment: Well I once did a hacky solution for something similar. You can in fact send php variables to javascript. `<script>var foo = "<? echo $bar; ?>"; alert(foo);</script>`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to populate the `InventoryUsage` dropdown you need to use JavaScript.
You can use the `onChange` event for the dropdown `InventoryID` then fetch the corresponding values via Ajax.

```
     $('#InventoryID').change(function () {
 var value =$(this).val(); // selected InventoryID option
 //get InventoryUsage values
 $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "myfile.php",
       data: { data: value },
       success: function(data){
         // Populate new dropdown $("#InventoryUsage")    
         // this is an example without knowing what is the returned data
         var Newoptions = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             Newoptions.push('<option value="',
             data[i].someValue, '">',
             data[i].someName, '</option>');
          }
        $("#InventoryUsage").html(Newoptions .join(''));

        }
         });
   });
});
```

then in your PHP file you need to handle the `$_POST['data']` , then query your database and return the drop-down options( Arrays ) that will be populated above...

edit :

If you are sure that this index matches the Inventory_Usage and that the InventoryUsage dropdown has previously been populated then
you could try to select the InventoryUsage option using the index of the InventoryID dropdown on change and load events...

try adding this function to you select :

```
    <select name="InventoryID" onChange="set_inventory_usage()"></select>
```

then add this script to your page's HEAD section..

```
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
            function set_inventory_usage(){

            // Change to getElementById if it is the ID not the name
            var Inventory_ID = document.getElementsByName('InventoryID')[0];

            var Inventory_Usage = document.getElementsByName('InventoryUsage')[0];

            // returns the index of the selected option in the InventoryID dropdown
            var InventorySelected = Inventory_ID.selectedIndex ; 


            // Sets the Usage dropdown to the same index as the Inventory selected option

            Inventory_Usage.selectedIndex = InventorySelected ;
          } 

        window.onload =  set_inventory_usage ;

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: OK, I already have to data from the database for all the InventoryID's InventoryUsage. Stored in an array called InventoryUsage.  I just need to display one of them depending on which InventoryID is selected. The POST in you code above has me a bit confused (never used ajax). Would the above solution still work if the data is already on the page?

Comment: How id the data on the Page ? No, you do not need to use this specific jQuery syntax but you need to perform an XMLHttpRequest in order to fetch new values dynamically. Hope this gets you started

Comment: What I meant is the page linked is called after the database query. I used ob_start and included the tpl page and sent all the variables to the page which were pulled from the database prior.       All the variables have the same index meaning that InventoryID['0']=ID3456 corresponds to InventoryUsage['0']=60. Therefore when InventoryID is ID3456 i would like to display the Number located at InventoryUsage['0']. I hope this adds some context to the problem and i apologise for not being clear before.

Comment: The index is determined by the php variable $i in my code snippit.              The $i would be changed to match the index of the InventoryID field. Say the value of InventoryUsage is 20 then i will display numbers 1 to 20.

Comment: So your inventoryUsage dropdown has already been populated and you look for a simple way to change the select whenver the inventoryID select changes. right ? And both have the same index .. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Without JavaScript, the best option is to add an `onchange` to your first dropdwon list, and when a value is selected submit the form. Since the form is not complete, and only the dropdown value and elements before that are passed, you can set a condition to query the database, get values based on first drop down and reload the form with those options. IThere is nothing wrong with this solution if done properly but to be honest I perfer to do such things with Ajax, hence option 2 below.

Option 2: [Learn some JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811605/do-i-need-to-learn-javascript-before-ajax-or-does-ajax-not-require-javascript-kn) and [use Ajax](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php) (Use caution when using other people's scripts in your system)

*Edit: Perhaps instead of wring Ajax code from scratch, use jQuery where most things are already done for you. Learning jQuery is very useful if you are going to do web development*

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. If time evades me I might have to use option one.

Comment: I ended up using a variation of the above option using onchange but saved the entered values in the session so on refresh they will still be entered.